# how to use MPI_Scatterv() properly

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, mpi

I am having a problem using `MPI_Scatterv` in a parallel program. Here is how it is defined :

```
int MPI_Scatterv(const void *sendbuf, const int *sendcounts,
    const int *displs, MPI_Datatype sendtype, void *recvbuf,
    int recvcount, MPI_Datatype recvtype, int root, MPI_Comm comm)
```

The way I understood it , the difference between `MPI_Scatterv` and `MPI_Scatter` is the fact that in `MPI_Scatterv` segments do not have to be of the same length and they don't have to be continuous (gaps in memory are allowed). The part I do not understand is if the `recvbuf` can be an array of different size for each process then what should be used for `recvcount`. Let's say I want to send 5 elements of sendbuf to process 0 and 15 to process 1. What should the value of `recvcount` be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each process has to call `MPI_Scatterv` with the right `recvcount`. You can pass a variable whose value depends on the rank of each process.

For example:

```
int recvcount = (rank == 0) ? 5 : 15;

MPI_Scatterv( sendbuf, sendcounts, displs, sendtype,
              recvbuf, recvcount, recvtype, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
```

Process with rank `0` calls `MPI_Scatterv` with a `recvcount` of `5` whereas process `1` passes a count of `15`.