# MPI scatter and gather multiple times

Tags: mpi

I have a problem with understanding scatter and gatter. Let's say I have one table[tableSize]. In that table I want to do some calculation for every 25 elements. I want to divide it among all the processes I have in my MPI. I try something like this

```
MPI_Scatter(table, 25, MPI_INT, tmpTable, 25, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
tmpTable[12] = doTheCalculation(tmpTable);
MPI_Gather(tmpTable, 25, MPI_INT, table, 25, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

But it works only if this **25 * number of processes = tableSize** is correct. How should I proceed if I would like to have tableSize of 125 but only 3 processes ran? My goal would be for process 0 and 1 to count twice (process 0 elements 1-25 and then 75-100 and process 1 to count 25-50 and 100-125). Is scatter and gather capable of doing this? Should I look into something else? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to scatter/gather with different counts, then you have to use `MPI_Scatterv()` and `MPI_Gatherv()`. A simple solution to your problem is to `MPI_Scatter()` followed by `MPI_Scatterv()`, and I believe that cannot be achieved in one shot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use of MPI\_Scatter if the set is not divisible among processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332313/use-of-mpi-scatter-if-the-set-is-not-divisible-among-processes)